# Schedule a DAG at different time by using Airflow REST API with conf variables

Tags: cron, airflow, cron-task, airflow-api

I want to scrape a website daily by using AirFlow and Selenium Grid server. I have created a single DAG for this. 
 
The website provide an endpoint (e.g. website.com/python, website.com/java, website.com/ruby) for each data in a same web user interface.

I've succesfully triggered The DAG by using AirFlow REST API with a conf variable. Now I want to schedule every run, which I have triggered, daily with the coressponding conf variable.
 Is it possible to achieve this (maybe by creating a new DAG or dynamically set a cronjob) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule an Airflow DAG by setting `schedule` on the `DAG`, for example:

```py
with DAG(dag_id="hello_world", start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule="@daily"):
    ...
```

From your question, it's unclear to me if your conf changes per DAG run. If not, you could hardcode all the settings, or set them through `params` on the DAG, see example [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to store every conf variable for each run inside `params` along with the execution time, and then schedule the DAG based on each run's execution time with its conf `params`